# Are commands supplied to system() visible to other users?

Tags: c, linux

I need to run a single curl command. The powers that be have decided this has to be done in C to avoid anyone being able to see the source code.

I don't know anything about C and have only little programming experience but I found you can use system() to execute a shell command like this:

```
int main()
{
system("/usr/bin/curl http://192.168.1.1");
return 0;
}
```

However, will there be a record/log anywhere in Linux (Ubuntu) that shows the full command my program executed?

Comment: Anyone (human or a process) running `ps` can see it.  There are plenty of ways that information is available.  Whether or not it is recorded anywhere will depend on the configuration, but you should not consider this in any way a good mechanism for hiding information.

Comment: Why do you need to do something like this? What is the reason you need to "hide" it? And remember that security through obscurity never really works.

Comment: If someone is curious they can run `strings your_binary | grep curl` and will get the full command used.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński Thank you. Unfortunately that does indeed show the whole command. Is there any way to avoid this? Otherwise I think I'll have to use libcurl.

Edit: Could you mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The bosses believe that somebody knowing that url + somehow obtaining admin credentials from a different source is a security risk. I think its pretty far fetched, there are much easier ways to achieve the as same but its not up for discussion.

Comment: @sjaak There is a stupid way to avoid the `strings` trick but it does not solve the underlying issue. To execute the command someone somewhere will have to read it so in the end it's impossible to hide it unless your have control over the whole stack - which you don't.

Comment: @sjaak To prove my point, what if someone runs wireshark and inspects the packets sent by curl?

Comment: there are many ways to obfuscate the code but it's quite easy to reverse engineer such a tiny program. For security you really need to use an encrypted connection like https

Comment: What will happen to you if the web request is reverse-engineered? That should be written in your question! And that could happen *without* access to your source code!

Comment: Your boss is probably wrong, on the technical level. You should discuss with him on who is responsible for technical mistakes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch While I don't disagree, that simply will not work. This is not a battle I will win so better to just do it the way they and actually get things done.

Comment: Be sure to keep written emails forcing you to code like you do. In case of trouble, you'll need them

Answer (score 4):

Anyone with access to your account will easily find out whatever you are trying to hide (using `strings` or `strace`).

Someone *without* said access (hopefully the whole world except you and your sysadmin) can still use `ps`. It won't make any difference whether you use a C wrapper or run the command directly: in both cases `ps` will show the command and its arguments in all their  glory.

Some commands, like `sqlplus`, manipulate their command line immediately after (although not exactly at) startup to hide e.g. password from prying eyes. `curl` does the same with usernames and passwords, but certainly not with URLs (which can be easily spied upon by network monitoring tools anyway)

On (post-3.2) linux, your sysadmin can (re-)mount `/proc` such that only `root` has access to your command lines, using the `hidepid` mount option

This will go a long way towards protecting your command lines - a C wrapper will only be useful for its placebo effect on your boss.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to run a single curl command. The powers that be have decided this has to be done in C to avoid anyone being able to see the source code.

You probably need to make a single [HTTP request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message). I recommend taking time to read some HTTP specification, like [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) or newer. Read also about [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2)

Consider using (from your C code) the [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) library for that (without using [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.hhtml) to run any [curl(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html) command). You need spend several days in reading about HTTP and libcurl.

Of course, someone could [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) your software (and find all details about your HTTP request and response),  and understand the involved [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See also [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Learn also more about C, e.g. by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Read also (and study documentation and source code) about the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and [ptrace(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html).

Don't forget that the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger are all [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html): you are allowed to download their source code, study it (it could take months), recompile that code (see [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/)), and improve them.

Comment: This is clearly the most sensible thing to do, but maybe a bit daunting for someone who admits not knowing anything about C. However, the `libcurl`  website has many excellent examples, like [this one](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html) that might need just a few adjustments to work. Tweaking existing code is a good way to learn, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There is no record/log of commands being executed by default. If you use bash, it has a history feature you can disable (with `HISTSIZE=0`).  cron logs commands to syslog.  `ps` will show processes that are currently running.  If you run your c-program with `ltrace` or `strace` it will trivially tell you what it is doing.  As will `strings` of the (stripped) binary.